# What do we learn from an isotope peak (or M+2 peak) in a mass spectrum?

Tags: molecules, mass-spectrometry

Mass spectrum of a molecule showed molecular ion peak and its isotopic 
 peak in 1:1 ratio. What is the possibility of the atom present in the 
 molecule?

Since it is mentioned that it has a molecular ion peak it gives the fact that it must be aromatics, olefins and not alcohols or branched hydrocarbons since the latter have less probability to show molecular ion peaks . Since they contain isotopic peaks it must mean they have chloro or bromo compounds. But I do not understand how to use ratios to identify the atom present in the molecule

Comment: The abundance of the isotopes of Chlorine 35:37 is approx 3:1 and is characteristic of chlorinated compounds.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Each element has different natural abundances for its isotopes. Two peaks with approximately 1:1 ratio indicates the presence of bromine. $\ce{^{79}Br}$ is the most common isotope, corresponding to $0.5069$ of naturally occurring bromine.  The isotopic composition for $\ce{^{81}Br}$ is $0.4931$.

What this means is that, for a molecule contaning a single bromine atom, approximately, half of the molecular ions will have $\ce{^{79}Br}$ and the other half will have $\ce{^{81}Br}$, resulting in two peaks with roughly the same intensity with $m/Z$ differing by two units.

References:

[1] https://www.nist.gov/pml/atomic-weights-and-isotopic-compositions-relative-atomic-masses

[2]https://chem.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Analytical_Chemistry/Supplemental_Modules_(Analytical_Chemistry)/Instrumental_Analysis/Mass_Spectrometry/Organic_Compounds_Containing_Halogen_Atoms

Comment: In addition to the peak pattern indicating the presence of bromine, it also indicates the _presence of a single bromine atom_ in the molecule.

Comment: @CurtF, thanks! Very good point. I'll edit that in answer.